# Retrieving stored nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello i migrated on new elasticSearch 5.1.1 and i had a problem with retrieving stored nested field. 
In old version (1.7.4) i used something like this:

```
{
 "query" : { ... }, 
 "fields" : [ 
     "priority", 
     "serviceItem.tariffSpaceAttribut", 
     "serviceItem.basicServiceAttribut", 
     "primaryKey"]
}
```

i get :

```
 "hits" : { 
   "hits" : [ { 
     "fields" : { 
         "serviceItem.tariffSpaceAttribut" : [ "TARIFF_FREE_EU_D_L" ],
         "priority" : [ 3 ],
         "primaryKey" : [ 39090 ] }
  }]}
```

**fields** option was replaced by **stored_fields** but i don't know how to make it work. When i use

```
...
"stored_fields" : [
    "priority",
    "serviceItem.tariffSpaceAttribut"
  ]
```

i get only priority field :

```
"hits": [
  {
     ...
    "fields": {
      "priority": [
        3
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I have set **"store" : true** for bow fields in my mapping.

How can i retrieve nested stored_fields in return fields not in _source. Thanks alot.

Comment: **stored_fields** doesn't not support in nested fields you must use `include_in_parent` but this property is @deprecated in newest version ES or you can use **copy_to**, i don't have any experience with this function.

Comment: So the best solution of this problem is use `_source` for retrieving all kind of fields.